# Reuse Certificate Signing Request(CSR) for APN/Development/Production

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Picture is worth 1000 words, but basically, should you generate a new for each of the 4 certificates or can I reuse the same one?

[image]

Comment: I've used the same one multiple times, it just a request file conatining the requester name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cert Signing Request is what ties the certificate back to the private key that is needed to sign apps.  Unless there is a specific reason you want to maintain separate private keys to allow different users access to build different things, I think it's easiest to keep a single CSR. For maintenance reasons, my team uses one key / CSR for our different certs.

Comment: If you share the CSR you have to be OK with sending the private keys to your team. If everyone has a separate CSR, you don't have to share keys. That said our 5 developer team uses one CSR.

Comment: thanks for your input. If I did want to avoid sharing private keys, I would generate 4 separate CSRs. The "Common Name" field could be used to as to hold a meaningful descriptioni?

Comment: You wouldn't generate the CSRs.  Each developer would generate their own CSR and provide it to you to generate the cert that will be tied to their private key (which only they would have).  The common name could be used to keep them straight.  Just be aware that if the developer leaves or loses their private key, the certificate is useless, as you can't use it for signing without the associated private key. Also, you (or whovever is the app owner) should generate the CSR for the app store distribution cert.

Comment: @wottle, thanks for the clarification about each developer. Before additional  developer are added, should I use the same CSR for my own ios developer cert and app store distribution cert? Same CSR for APN sandbox and APN Production?

Comment: I would recommend having a different CSRT / private key for development than for production.  Sharin a dev cert can be common among teams at a company, but you want to really protect the private key and cert for the app store distribution certs.